# Cannot import Yarn Workspaces module in NestJS

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, yarn-workspaces

I have a monorepo that has the following structure:

- frontend
- backend - NestJS
- shared

In the shared folder I keep all the DTOs that are used by both frontend and backend.

Sometime of the interfaces I try to import into the backend project throw the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '@prefix/shared/dto/user'
Require stack:
- /dev/proj/backend/dist/src/user/dto/user.dto.js
- /dev/proj/backend/dist/src/user/user.controller.js
- /dev/proj/backend/dist/src/user/user.module.js
```

The code that throws the error ('/backend/src/user/dto'):

```
import { CreateUserRequestDto, CreateUserResponseDto } from '@prefix/shared/dto/user'
```

The only way I found to make this work is to import them in the same file but create some new interfaces that implement the DTOs. But that's a cumbersome workaround and implies I have to copy a lot of code.

Some thoughts:

- The problem seems to be mainly when I import the @prefix/shared module in the NestJS Controller
- Maybe some TS config so I attached my config as well

tsconfig.build.json

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "test", "dist", "**/*spec.ts"]
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "rootDir": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "allowUnusedLabels": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./typings", "node_modules/@types"],
    "alwaysStrict": false
  }
}
```